# Claasification of testdata containg string columns

Tags: python, dataframe, classification, random-forest

So I am using Machine Learning to predict class of some data as given below sample.
My data is related to some scheduler running on server and by submission time and server_type I am labeling the class

```
Dataframe: df= sch_name  server_type  subit_time   submit_by    Class
               RCALCAPP  X3333        165703       AAAA         1
               RCALCAPP  X3333        105703       BBBB         0
               PCALCAPP  X3333        165703       AAAA         1
               .
               .
               TCALCAPP  X3344        095703       CCCC         0
```

TO run classifier I am doing lableencoding for string column values. Not sure if  it is correct approch to ecode or not but it is working for me

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

Also I dont need submit_by column to train  classifier so I am removing it

```
featureNames = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['submit_by','status']]
```

TO prepare a model I have splitted above dataframe into training, cv, test and using below

```
trainFeatures = training[featureNames].values
trainClasses  = training['status'].values

testFeatures= test[featureNames].values
testClasses  = test['status'].values
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(trainFeatures, trainClasses)
score = clf.score(testFeatures, testClasses)
print(score) #.99823742
```

Till here every thing is okay.classifier is running on data. But nowI want to test new new record for classification. I tried to do following:

```
test_sch = ['TCALCAPP',  'X3344',  '075703']
class_code = clf.predict(test_sch) # [1]
```

It gave error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'TCALCAPP'
```

And I know the reason as It has not been encoded to number. Here is my problem how to do that exactly. I need to pass encoded value for 'TCALCAPP',  'X3344'. But How I would know encoded value for a new test data. My approach could be wrong but requirement is same as above. Kindly help.

Comment: You need to encode your testing dataset as well like you did for training set. Use LabelEncoder() on test data.

Comment: Alright, Let us assume for my training data  under sch_name column 
value 'TCALCAPP'  has been encoded as 2. For a new test data 
value  'TCALCAPP'  If I do encoding it may or may not be 2.But It is necessary that encoding for 'TCALCAPP' should remain same for training data and same data otherwise It would give wrong result.

Comment: One workaround is to use the entire dataset for encoding purpose and then split into train and test. So your encoding will remain intact.